# Redirect to subdirectory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301, http-status-code-302

I have a website structured like this:

example.com (Running Prestashop)

example.com/blog (Running wordpress).

I wanted my site visitors to go to the blog during crowdfunding. Hence I added this in the .htaccess:

```bash
# This allows you to redirect index.html to a specific subfolder
Redirect /index.php http://example.com/blog/
```

The site is redirecting as planned but I have the following questions from SEO point of view:

1. The main site has not been submitted to search engines. Should I remove the redirect, submit it and then add the redirect for a good SEO?
2. Is there going to be an impact on SEO for using `Redirect /index.php http://example.com/blog/`?
3. Implications if I use redirect since day 1 of submission where I state it as an e-commerce platform.
4. Is there any better way to obtain said results ie point exmaple.com to example.com/blog?

Thank you in advance. Please keep SEO in mind as we expect big traffic during crowdfunding and we dont want to lose SEO.

Comment: Thanks a ton Mike for cleaning up my mistake in formatting :)